# Asp.net C# Unable to retrieve html5 input value in backend

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a page similar to the following:

```
<input class="form-control" name="searchParam" id="searchParam" runat="server">
<button class="btn btn-primary" onserverclick="getDetails" runat="server" >Lookup Details</button>
```

Below is the server code:

```
   protected void getDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    String paramVal = searchParam.Value;// ourBin.Value;
    if (paramVal != null && paramVal != "")
    {
        //do processing.
    }
}
```

ParamVal is always null.

I am unable put the input and button controls in form because the page is using Master page that declares form where the page content goes- thus when I add form tags it always complains. However I've ignored the warning and use form but no succes. I've tried `searchParam.Value` ,`Master.Request.Form` , `Request.Form` and as well `Request.QueryString` with the appropriate keys but no luck. I've also tried asp button but it doesn't get fired when clicked. Anything am missing, this my first asp.net htlml 5 app.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please show your related server code?

Comment: What do you mean by 'unable to use form'? It is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a server side control so you cannot get its handle on the server side